# testing for game algorithm speed

Tags: java, algorithm, testing, artificial-intelligence

How should I test my algorithm in terms of speed? The enhanced algorithm I made and the original algorithm search the same depth and they both give the same move, they only differ in terms of speed.

Do you know how I should test my new algorithm that I made? Aside from just subtracting the system time it started to system time it ended. What I'm trying to say is I need to do a little formal tests with little bit of formulas. Should I simulate all possible moves and tally the time each algorithm (enhanced and original) took time to decide on a move? I'm quite clueless here.

Comment: What kind of game is it? Can two AI play against each other?

Comment: Is the algorithm based on min-max algorithm? If so - comparing times might be not such a good idea to compare the two.

Comment: it's a board game, the two AI can play against each other but I won't need them to, since I'm only testing their speed. What I know is, the modified algorithm is generally faster. I just don't know how to formally state how much faster it is than the original algorithm. For example, I can state that it is 20% faster than the original algorithm in choosing a move after testing different types of scenarios. I'm actually making my thesis.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the below method a few times and have had success. If you are interested in multi-threaded benchmarking refer to the link at the bottom of the page.

**Timing a single-threaded task using CPU, system, and user time**
Timing a single-threaded task using CPU, system, and user time

- "User time" is the time spent running your application's own code.
- "System time" is the time spent running OS code on behalf of your
  application (such as for I/O).

Java 1.5 introduced the java.lang.management package to monitor the JVM. The entry point for the package is the ManagementFactory class. It's static methods return a variety of different "MXBean" objects that report JVM information. One such bean can report thread CPU and user time.

Call ManagementFactory . getThreadMXBean() to get a ThreadMXBean that describes current JVM threads. The bean's getCurrentThreadCpuTime() method returns the CPU time for the current thread. The getCurrentThreadUserTime() method returns the thread's user time. Both of these report times in nanoseconds (but see Appendix on Times and (lack of) nanosecond accuracy).

Be sure to call isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported() first, though. If it returns false (rare), the JVM implementation or OS does not support getting CPU or user times. In that case, you're back to using wall clock time.

```
import java.lang.management.*;

/** Get CPU time in nanoseconds. */
public long getCpuTime( ) {
    ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
    return bean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported( ) ?
        bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime( ) : 0L;
}

/** Get user time in nanoseconds. */
public long getUserTime( ) {
    ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
    return bean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported( ) ?
        bean.getCurrentThreadUserTime( ) : 0L;
}

/** Get system time in nanoseconds. */
public long getSystemTime( ) {
    ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
    return bean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported( ) ?
        (bean.getCurrentCpuTime( ) - bean.getCurrentThreadUserTime( )) : 0L;
}
```

These methods return the CPU, user, and system time since the thread started. To time a task after the thread has started, call one or more of these before and after the task and take the difference:

```
long startSystemTimeNano = getSystemTime( );
long startUserTimeNano   = getUserTime( );
... do task ...
long taskUserTimeNano    = getUserTime( ) - startUserTimeNano;
long taskSystemTimeNano  = getSystemTime( ) - startSystemTimeNano;
```

Taken from, http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking#TimingasinglethreadedtaskusingCPUsystemandusertime

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program to capture timings, you can change this to suit your needs:

```
package com.quicklyjava;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // start time
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Sleeping Zzzz... " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    long difference = System.nanoTime() - time;
    System.out.println("It took " + difference + " nano seconds to finish");

 }

}
```

And here is the output:

```
Sleeping Zzzz... 0
Sleeping Zzzz... 1
Sleeping Zzzz... 2
Sleeping Zzzz... 3
Sleeping Zzzz... 4
It took 5007507169 nano seconds to finish
```